# Center TextViews/ImageViews vertically in unknown height - Android

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, gravity

Screenshot is posted below.  In each row, the last 3 columns are not centered in their row vertically.  The height of each row is unknown until after the screen is displayed.  I am not sure but I am guessing I need to find the height of the row dynamically after everything is displayed and then center everything.  Is that the correct route?

Below is a snipper of XML code for this class.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="65"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" > 

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/q1Image"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q1Question"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp" /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q1Answer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="27"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"  /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q1Verse"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"  /> 
            </LinearLayout>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/q2Image"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q2Question"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp" /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q2Answer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="27"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp" /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q2Verse"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"  /> 
            </LinearLayout>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/q3Image"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q3Question"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"  />  

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q3Answer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="27"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"  /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q3Verse"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"  /> 
            </LinearLayout>

//Rows 4-10 code excluded because of repetition.
```

[image]

Comment: Dude, you should use ListView instead of this static LinearLayout in your XML.

Comment: I am not familiar with ListView.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: ListView (and his brothers to the "AdapterView" family: AdapterViewFlipper, ExpandableListView, Gallery, GridView, ListView, Spinner, StackView) Is a view with a purpose of populating items during run-time, when you have a large amount of rows or when you know their contents only during run time. 
ListView gives you a simple way to define one item in the list and then populate that list with repeating items, that is made with the help of Adapter. Read more @ web, it's great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set android:layout_gravity to center_vertical on your text views.

Basically, since your layout_height is set to wrap content, your text views look like this:

```
-------
content
-------
```

The text view aligns with its parent like so:

```
-------
-------
content
-------




-------
```

Your goal is to get the view to center itself within the parent vertically. The attribute "layout_gravity" tells the view how to adjust itself within its parent. Therefore, setting layout_gravity to center_vertical will tell the view to be centered within its parent, like so:

```
-------


-------
content
-------


-------
```

Another way this can be accomplished is with the "gravity" attribute. The "gravity" attribute tells a parent how to layout its content (as opposed to "layout_gravity", which defines tells the view how to sit within its parent). So another possible solution would be to tell the list view to align all of its content centered vertically. This is done by specifying android:gravity="center_vertical" on the ViewGroup (in your case the LinearLayout).

Comment: Would the height of each ````TextView```` be the same for the whole row and therefore center the whole row to make it look nice?  Like in row 2 of the screenshot for example, one ````TextView```` is 3 lines tall and the other 2 are 1 line each.

Comment: If I understood your question right, you were wondering about how to vertically center text in a row. I'll update my answer with details on how to center content, and in the meantime you should try specifying that attribute I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Ah perfect!  Works exactly how I wanted it to.  Thank you @WindyB!